# Need to show shortcodes to next line on json array

Tags: wordpress, newline, shortcode

I have created a shortcode functions to display the plan details for each U.S states. For that I have made JSON array to have U.S state details. What I need is, I want to show the plan details line by line using shortcode function. I need suggestions, below I have shared you the code.

```
$STATES_ARRAY   = array(
    array(
    "slugCode" => "alabama",
    "name" => "Alabama",
    "stateCode" => "AL",
    "plans"=> "Blue Cross and Blue Shield of Alabama, CGS Administrators LLC, Palmetto GBA LLC"
    ),
);

add_shortcode('US_STATE_PLAN', 'mp_usstate_plan');

function mp_usstate_plan() {
 
            $usstate_plan = "";
            $chosen_state = [];
            global $STATES_ARRAY;
            //$states = json_encode(STATES_ARRAY);
            //alert("Value of States Array" + $STATES_ARRAY);
            //$state = $states.find(state => state.slugCode === get_query_var("usstate"));
            $state = array_filter($STATES_ARRAY, function($state) {
                return $state["slugCode"] === get_query_var("usstate");
            });
            
            if(count($state) > 0){
                $chosen_state = array_pop($state);
                if(!empty($chosen_state) ){ 
                    $usstate_plan = $chosen_state["plans"]; 
                }
             }
            
            return $usstate_plan; 

        }
```